# How to create separate login accounts using firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image: Firebase]

I would like to ask how do I create two separate login intents. For example, One is for a customer and one is for the admin to check the details.

```
private void userLogin()
{
    String email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passText.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.isEmpty())
    {
        emailText.setError("Email is required");
        passText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
    {
        emailText.setError("Please Enter a Valid email");
        passText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password.isEmpty())
    {
        emailText.setError("Password is required");
        passText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password.length()<6)
    {
        emailText.setError("Minimum length of Password is 6");
        passText.requestFocus();
    }
    mProgress.show();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Placeorder.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //Clears all activity and open a new one
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void onLoginClick(View view) {

    userLogin();
}
```

In this code, it can only show the customer part, but how do I input another way where there is separate use for admin or the one managing and for the customer?

Updated one

```
mProgress.show();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String userID = user.getUid();
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID);
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        if(value == "Grocer")
                        {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Placeorder.class);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //Clears all activity and open a new one
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

[image: Firebase Database]

[image: Firebase updated sturcture database]

Code to make structure

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID).child("Grocer");    
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email1,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        String userID = user.getUid();
                        myRef.child("First Name").setValue(first_name1);
                        myRef.child("Last Name").setValue(last_name1);
                        myRef.child("Email").setValue(email1);
                        myRef.child("Number").setValue(numbers1);
                        myRef.child("Grocer").setValue(grocer);
                        myRef.child("isAdmin").setValue(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set a check in your database and when user login in your app then you should check that user is customer or admin in your database after that you have to flow your intent according to your app, set a boolean value in database like this :-

```
boolean isAdmin ;
```

and when user login in your app then compare uid is registered with admin or customer and set your result in true or false in isAdmin filed :-

```
if(isAdmin){
// user is admin
}else{
// user is customer
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193656/discussion-on-answer-by-sandeep-malik-how-to-create-separate-login-accounts-usin).